# Java listener must inherit from java.util.EventListener - why?

Tags: java, events, listener

In the javadoc it says that EventListener is

> "A tagging interface that all event listener interfaces must extend."

Why is that? What's the significance of making a custom listener implement EventListner? Is there any special handling for EventListner somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably used by [javabeans introspection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html).

For instance Netbeans beaninfo editor does not recognise the event if `extends EventListener` is missing from the Listener.

Answer (score 7):

It’s only important if you want to use an [EventListenerList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) or an [EventListenerProxy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListenerProxy.html). I like to use it on my own event listener interfaces as well, though. It makes the purpose of the interface much clearer.

Comment: Can't you just make your interface extend EventListener and get the best of both worlds?

Comment: That’s exactly what I do so what is the other world you’re talking of? :)

Comment: EventListener is required by the javabeans introspection code.

Comment: EventListener is defined in java.util.  EventListenerList and EventLIstenerProxy are not.  This did not answer the question.